ssh connection refused using DDNS name
Following upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, I receive "connection refused" message from any machine in my local network. This happens only using DDNS names, while IPs work. This happens only on the Ubuntu 24.04 laptop.
I was not able to find any solution online.
Port forwarding on my router is fine.
There is no firewall on the laptop.
If I run sshd -d on the remote ssh server, I cannot see any connection attempt from the "faulty" laptop.
I reverted from ssh.socket to sshd.service with the following commands:
sudo systemctl disable --now ssh.socket
sudo systemctl enable --now sshd.service


nslookup asds.dynu.net 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xxxx.dynu.net
Address: 94.999.99.99

UPDATE: I finalized this question by mistake, many details were missing. Luckily, this turned me in the right direction thanks to the answer below: I thought nslookup output from my DDNS was right, but it wasn't. So this is not an SSH-something problem, I will look into DDNS-related problems now.

You dodn't include output from nslookup or host in your answer or the ip address you are trying to connect to, so any answer would have to make a lot of assumptions.

You are right, actually I sent out the answer by mistake, I was planning to add all the details. Thanks

Connections to other machines always use ip addresses, not hostnames.  If you supply a hostname it must be translated to an ip address before it can be used.
If using the ip address works and using the hostname fails, then the hostname is mapping to a different ip address. (Assuming you aren't getting host not found...)
It doesn't matter that nslookup doesn't get errors, it matters what answer it gets!  Note also that the nslookup command uses a different (more direct) source to look up the hostname than other things like host so it could possibly get different answers.  If you get different answers from nslookup and host, likely host is pulling a cached answer from the local system.  (nslookup may also pull a cached answer but with fewer cache layers.)

thanks, I ran nslookuo on other machines in y LAN to find out the problem is actually DDNS resolution, not SSH service. No idea how to fix it since all the other devices are ok, but I will look in to it before sending another question. Thanks to point me in the right direction

Another question is probably a good idea.  Comparing answers of nslookup to host is the first step in determining if there is a dns problem.
